# Remove first part of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to remove the first part of the string and the comma that seperates the string.

Current code that produces data:

```
SELECT PrizeMoneyBreakDown from race2;
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,';',1)),';',-1) AS 1st,
FROM race2
```

Data:

```
1st,4000    
1st,4550
1st,4550    
1st,4550    
1st,4550
```

Desired output:

```
4000
4550
4550
4550
4550
```

Comment: You are testing for ; (semi-colon) in substring_index but your data has , (comma) is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will take the 5-th character of the string till the end :

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,5,length(PrizeMoneyBreakDown)) as st1
FROM race2
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae0a8d556e07ed5dc549203b9a0ef4fd)

Or using your method, change the `;` with `;` and `1` to `-1` to take the second part of the string

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,',',-1)),',',1) AS 1st
FROM race2
```

Comment: Thanks. This leave me with a semi-colon at the end of the outputed data. How do I remove this?

Comment: @kjdcwckj you could use replace , check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d6d5de93bd80e94235c34106798605e